Filtering pgvectorStore in asRetriever function
I have an app using Langchain.js in Express, Prisma ORM, Postgres and PGVector. I have the below function that performs a similarity search on the DB based on an array of answers that comes through:
const retriever = pgvectorStore.asRetriever({
    verbose: true,
    k: 25,
    searchType: "similarity",
    filter: {
      iron_catergory: answers[4],
      varient_price: { lt: answers[1] },
      dexterity: answers[0],
      shaft_flex: answers[3],
      length: answers[5],
    },
  });

Below is the Prisma schema:
model golfClubs4Cash_irons_online {
  id                 String @id
  varient_sku        String
  title              String
  varient_price      Int
  price_range        String
  url                String
  image              String
  brand              String
  club_model         String
  set_makeup         String
  iron_catergory     String
  dexterity          String
  condition          String
  shaft_flex         String
  shaft_material     String
  number_of_clubs    String
  shaft_model        String
  location           String
  length_to_standard String
  length_inches      String
  length             String
  store_id           Int
}

model ironsvector_online {
  id       String                @id @default(uuid())
  content  String
  metadata Json
  vector   Unsupported("vector")
}

The issue is with the varient_price filter. yes, I know it's spelling of varient is wrong but it is consistently wrong across the code. I am trying to filter all varient_price less than answers[1]. For some reason I cannot figure out is this filter is not working. I think I'm using the right syntax and when I run the program the data comes through as below but returns an empty array:
filter: {
    iron_catergory: 'Midsize Players',
    varient_price: { 'lt': 750 },
    dexterity: 'Right-Handed',
    shaft_flex: 'Stiff',
    length: 'Standard'
  }

If I remove the varient_price filter I get values returned. What am I doing wrong?
